# Only the first image uploads

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

I am trying to upload these two images to my site:
https://listing-images.homejunction.com/maris/82721628/photo_1.jpg
https://listing-images.homejunction.com/maris/82721628/photo_2.jpg

But only the first image works. I am using the following code, where $post_id is the post to attach these images to:

```
media_sideload_image( 'https://listing-images.homejunction.com/maris/82721628/photo_1.jpg', $post_id, '','id' );
media_sideload_image( 'https://listing-images.homejunction.com/maris/82721628/photo_2.jpg', $post_id, '','id' );
```

I have tried other methods of uploading and attaching images, but the upload seems to always fail. I can upload photo_1 multiple times, but photo_2 does not work. Either it doesn't upload at all or it's a blank image.

Debugging shows the WP_ERROR prints the following:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_404] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
            [http_404] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 444
                    [body] => 
                )

        )

    [additional_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I am unsure what to make of this message.
How can I get both images uploaded and attached to a post?

Comment: If the first image uploads properly, then your code works, so you can try [enabling debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and check the logs for any relevant errors/messages.

Comment: That function returns a `WP_Error` object with an error message describing what the problem was, you should assign it to a variable and look at the message

Comment: "Debugging shows the WP_ERROR that returns is a http_404 code without a message" - I looked at the [revision](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/387917/2) and noticed you passed `$image` "as-is" to `file_put_contents()`, hence no messages were logged - try with `is_wp_error( $image ) ? $image->get_error_message() : $image` or simply `print_r( $image, true )`..